# $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\sum_{r=0}^{n-1}\sum_{k=0}^{n-r}(-1)^k\frac{2n+3}{k!(2n+3-k)!} (1+n-r-k)^{2n+1}=0$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, limits, convergence-divergence, asymptotics

I'm trying to prove that

$$\sum_{r=0}^{n-1}\sum_{k=0}^{n-r}(-1)^k\frac{2n+3}{k!(2n+3-k)!}
(1+n-r-k)^{2n+1}$$

converges to zero as $n\rightarrow\infty$. The conjecture came from the computations on Mathematica:

```
f[n_] := Sum[
  Sum[(-1)^k (2 n + 
      3) (1 + n - r - k)^(2 n + 1)/(k! (2 n + 3 - k)!), {k, 0, 
    n - r}], {r, 0, n - 1}]
ListLinePlot[{Table[f[n], {n, 100}]}]
```

[Plot for 1≤n≤100](https://i.stack.imgur.com/36Tw3.png)

And the motivation for the problem is [this article](https://projecteuclid.org/download/pdf_1/euclid.tjm/1296483473) where I evaluate

$$\sum_{r=0}^{n-1}\nu(\mathbf{A}_{0,1}(n-r,n+r))-\nu(\mathbf{A}_{1,0}(n-1-r,n+1+r))=$$

Current trials: I can rewrite the sum as

$$\sum_{r=0}^{n-1}\sum_{k=0}^{n-r}(-1)^k\binom{2n+3}{k}
\frac{(1+n-r-k)^{2n+1}}{(2n+2)!}$$

and remove the $(2n+2)!$ from the inner sum since it doesn't depend on $k$:

$$\sum_{r=0}^{n-1}\frac{1}{(2n+2)!}\sum_{k=0}^{n-r}(-1)^k\binom{2n+3}{k}
(1+n-r-k)^{2n+1}$$

Then if I fix $r$, the inner sum is asymptotic to $(1+i-r)^{2i+1}$ (the factor $k=0$ prevails over the rest). However, I cannot just sum the asymptotes since asymptotic functions doesn't behave well with summation.

Any suggestion will be great (it doesn't need to be a complete solution)!

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first asymptotic term is 
$$ S_n \sim \frac{1}{2}\sqrt{\frac{3}{\pi}} \, (n+1)^{-3/2} .$$
The proof depends on series manipulations to get an expression in which an inner sum has a closed form, and the resulting single sum has a known (to me) asymptotic form. From the proposer's form

$$ (2n+1)!\,S_n = \sum_{r=0}^{n-1}\sum_{k=0}^{n-r} (-1)^k \binom{2n+3}{k} (1+n-r-k)^{2n+1} $$
let $r\to r+n$ in the summand, take the negative of the outer summation index, and furthermore shift the outer index by one; i.e.,
$$ (2n+1)!\,S_n = \sum_{r=2}^{n+1}\sum_{k=0}^{r} (-1)^k \binom{2n+3}{k} (r-k)^{2n+1}.$$

Now let $k \to r-k$ and notice the inner sum can then be extended to infinity:
$$ (2n+1)!\,S_n = \sum_{r=2}^{n+1}\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} (-1)^{r+k} \binom{2n+3}{r-k} k^{2n+1}.$$
We can exchange summations and perform explicitly the inner sum.  With Mathematica and some simplification we find, letting $N = n+1, $

$$ \sum_{r=2}^{N} (-1)^r \binom{2N+1}{r-k} = (-1)^N\binom{2N}{N+k}
+ \frac{(2N)!}{(1-k)!(2N+k-1)!}.$$
The last term is non-zero only for $k=1$.  Therefore we have

$$ (2n+1)!\,S_n = \sum_{k=1}^{N} (-1)^{k+N}k^{2N-1}\binom{2N}{N+k} -1.$$  When solving for $S_n,$ the last term is exponentially small and can be dropped.  Using the technique I mentioned in MSE 2720893, one can show how such an expression is related to the Eulerian numbers, and use their known asymptotics to find

$$ \sum_{k=1}^{N} (-1)^{k+N}k^{2N-1}\binom{2N}{N+k} \sim (2N-1)! \sqrt{\frac{3}{\pi\,N}}.$$  A factorial identity and algebra completes the proof.

Comment: Cool! I'm gonna read carefully tonight. I'm just wondering for now: How do you find such simplification with Mathematica? That would be very helpful to me.

Also, the MSE 2720893 is almost the same thing, the difference is that here I'm getting all the Eulerian Numbers in a certain line (thus the $\sum_{r=0}^i$) and there it was taken only the central Eulerian Numbers (which is the case $r=0$ for myself).

Comment: Very nice solution, for sure !

Comment: Although I understand everything up to the simplification of the double sum into a single sum, I still have to figure out the asymptotics given in Math Overflow 294590. That's pretty hard! But thanks nonetheless

Answer (score 2):

*This is not a proof at all.*

I have the feeling that I saw this question or a very similar one during the last days (and I was unable to do anything - I was hoping that some hypergeometric functions could appear somewhere).

Using a CAS, I made the calculations up to $n=1000$ (this took a real long time !).

From the results, what it seems to me is that 
$$S_n=\sum_{r=0}^{n-1}\sum_{k=0}^{n-r}(-1)^k\binom{2n+3}{k}
\frac{(1+n-r-k)^{2n+1}}{(2n+2)!}\approx \frac {a_n}{n^{3/2}}$$ and that (more or less) $\lim_{n\to \infty } \, a_n=\frac12$.
$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
n & S_n & \frac 1 {2n^{3/2}} \\
 100 & 0.000481006 & 0.000500000\\
 200 & 0.000171396 & 0.000176777\\
 300 & 0.000093540 & 0.000096225\\
 400 & 0.000060836 & 0.000062500\\
 500 & 0.000043565 & 0.000044721\\
 600 & 0.000033158 & 0.000034021 \\
 700 & 0.000026323 & 0.000026998 \\
 800 & 0.000021551 & 0.000022097 \\
 900 & 0.000018065 & 0.000018519 \\
1000 & 0.000015427 & 0.000015811
\end{array}
\right)$$

The big question is : how to prove it ? I shall very interested to see a rigorous proof.

Comment: Interesting... what CAS do you use? And how did you come up with $\frac{a_n}{n^{3/2}}$?

Comment: @user559748. No CAS required for that; just computing big numbers. You got a very nice solution from skbmoore. Funny is $\frac{1}{2}\sqrt{\frac{3}{\pi}}\approx 0.488603$.